# Construct fixed-size array in variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I want to construct an array of 8 integers in a variadic function. No problem:

```
template <typename... Ints>
void foo(Ints... ints) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(Ints) < 8, "some useful error");

    const int my_array[8] = {ints...};
}
```

That even automatically zero initializes the array, so if I call `foo(1, 2, 3)` I will get an array like `{1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`.

Now what if I want to default to something other than zero? Like, say -1. This works:

```
template <int Def>
struct Int {
    Int() : val(Def) { }
    Int(int i): val(i) { }

    inline operator int() const { return val; }

    int val;
};

template <typename... Ints>
void foo(Ints... ints) {
    const Int<-1> my_array_def[8] = {ints...};
    const int* my_array = reinterpret_cast<const int*>(my_array_def);
}
```

But is there a simpler way that doesn't rely upon having this extra type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use another template:

```
template <typename... Ints>
auto foo(Ints... ints) -> typename std::enable_if<sizeof...ints==8>::type {
    const int my_array[] = {ints...};
}
template <typename... Ints>
auto foo(Ints... ints) -> typename std::enable_if<sizeof...ints<8>::type {
    return foo(ints..., -1);
}
```